# Set multiple options as selected in select input using javascript

Tags: javascript

Thank you for taking the time to read my question.

I have an array of values I'm sending to my HTML form that I want to use to pre select in my list in my form. My select list is "multiple"

```
<select id="idResourceName" name="ResourceName" form="carform" multiple="true">
            
</select>
```

Say the list has 10 values, but my array has 2, I'd like to preselect the 2 from the list in my form.

Here is what I've tried so far based on other posts... but I'm not getting anywhere.

```
var item = document.getElementById("idResourceName");
        ResourcesArr.forEach(function(r){
          //var option = document.createElement("option");
          //option.textContent = r[0];
          //item.appendChild(option);
          window.alert(r);
          for(var i, j = 0; i = item.options[j]; j++) {
              if(i.value == r) {
                  //item.selectedIndex = j;
                  windows.alert(item.options[i]);
                  //break;
              }
          }
        });
```

if I uncomment this line, and comment out the next, I get the first value in my array to work, but the second doesn't... that is I get one value preselected in my list.

Really appreciate your time and any help you can give.

thanks

tried using other posts

Comment: set prop option is `selected`

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the below code which might solve your problem.

```html
var item = document.getElementById("idResourceName");
item.selectedIndex = [];
ResourcesArr.forEach(function(r){
  for(var i, j = 0; i = item.options[j]; j++) {
    if(i.value == r) {
      if (ResourcesArr.includes(i.value)) {
        item.selectedIndex.push(j);
      }
    }
  }
});
item.selectedIndex = item.selectedIndex;
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you Hitesh! I gave it a try but it only selects one of the values in my list (the first one in the array). I have 2 values in the array I tested.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestion of Hitesh, I was able to sort something out.

```js
var item = document.getElementById("idResourceName");
        var selectedIndex = [];
        ResourcesArr.forEach(
          function (r){
            for (let i = 0;i < item.options.length;i++) {
              if(item.options[i].value == r.trimStart()){
                item.options[i].selected = true;
              }
            }
          }
        );
```

I'm don't totally understand the example but I think my code is close(?). I also think the main difference is just marking each item in the list box as selected as it loops instead of adding to an array... at least my code finally worked when I did that change.

Thanks!